# Using VS code with the 'MATLAB Runner' extension returns an error

Tags: matlab, plugins, path, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use VS code with the 'MATLAB Runner' extension. I have updated my  'user settings' json file according to the instructions:

[image: setting]

but when I try to run code, I get the following error:

> Could not find path to the matlab executable.

[image: error]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using MATLAB R2016a on Windows. This is unfortunate, as [the readme for "MATLAB Runner"](https://github.com/eamon-bell/matlab-runner) clearly states that:

> ## Please Note
>
> This extension works best on mac as Matlab does not fully support running the executable from command prompt. **Also, versions prior to 2017 will not work on windows at all.**

Thus, if you insist on using the plugin, you should update your MATLAB version or switch operating systems.